# Doesn't ANSI C allow printing each character at a same place after a fixed time period?

Tags: c, c89

I am trying to generate random numbers to be printed on the console. I am programming in C on Linux. I wanted to print all the numbers at a single place after a time interval of a second for each number.
I am using `sleep()` for stopping a 'time interval'. I tried `\b`, `\r` and all but none works.
I just wanted this to run, *for example*:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\b");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "none works"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend some time learning about the etiquette here. Please read the FAQ carefully and then go back to your previous questions. Please accept the answer the most addresses your problem and vote up other answers that are helpful and informative.

Comment: I didn't know the \b escape didn't work on Linux terminal consoles. Is it true?

Comment: I would use \r here, and if that doesn't work then your terminal settings are confused.

Comment: Definitely not ANSI C...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stdout is probably buffered, so flush it.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
   printf("%d",i);
   fflush(stdout);
   sleep(1);
   printf("\b");
 }
```

Comment: Yup. And this is instructive, so the OP should understand *why* this is important. But use curses. Really.

Comment: This is the right answer. Don't use curses unless you want a fullscreen program. Curses is not usable for simple progress bars and the like in programs that want their main output to be part of the main terminal scroll.

Comment: this helped a lot and it works the way i wanted. But how does the stdout gets buffered every time i run the program?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest answer is probably to use [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html):

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   
    int i;

    initscr(); /* Start curses mode */

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
            mvprintw(0,0, "%d", i); /* coords 0,0 */
            refresh(); /* Update screen */
            sleep(1);
    }

    getch(); /* Wait for user input */
    endwin(); /* End curses mode */

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -o counter counter.c -lncurses`.