# Can someone please explain line-by-line what this short, simple C program does and how I can run it?

Tags: c, ncurses

```
#include<curses.h> //includes the curses library so it can be used in the function
main()
{ //opening main method
    int i; //declare int i
    initscr(); //creates a terminal of a specific type?
    noecho(); // turn off echoing 
    for (i=0; I <5; i++) //loops from 0 to 4
        getch(); //takes one character from the keyboard, I think ?
    endwin();
} //restores the terminal
```

I am not sure about what this simple program is doing, and cannot seem to run it either ? 
Could someone please help me out here ?

Comment: I don't know what could be added, that isn't already there in the comments.

Comment: Care to tell us why doesn't it run? What error does it give?? Is it during compile or as soon as it runs? Please give more detail.

Comment: Presumably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056247/doesnt-ansi-c-allow-printing-each-character-at-a-same-place-after-a-fixed-time-p/5056394#5056394, though if so user has dropped the body of the loop. And misspelled `i` as `I`. To compiler you'll need the ncurses headers (see the `#include`?) and to link against ncurses (`-lncurses` with gcc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
initscr(); //This method initialize the current and standard screen
noecho(); // turn off echoing 
for (i=0; i <5; i++) //loops from 0 to 4
getch(); //YES you thinks right, it takes one character from the keyboard.
endwin();  //The endwin() function restores the terminal, by flushing any output to the  terminal and moving the cursor to the first column of the last line of the screen.
```